# Как получить данные из XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

как получить данные тега по определённому атрибуту(id)
допустим данные 54 атрибута.
http://joxi.ru/v29Q4Y5TZzdqZ2

Answer (score 0):

Можешь реализовать на основе данного примера:

**(file.xml)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <item type="Language">
        <name>PHP</name>
        <link>www.php.net</link>
    </item>
    <item type="Database">
        <name>Java</name>
        <link>www.oracle.com/br/technologies/java/‎</link>
    </item>
</list>
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
        $role = $child->attributes();
        foreach($child as $key => $value) {
            if($role == "Language") {
                echo("[".$key ."] ".$value . "<br />");
            }
        }
}
```

**Результат:**

```
[name] PHP
[link] www.php.net
```

Источники:

- PHP.net: https://www.php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes
- Еще твоя тема на англоязычных источниках: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml